# Bug in current version of Xcode 4.6.3 (BOOL is showing wrong)

Tags: xcode4, boolean

[image]

Take a look at the picture please: the value of the variable "success" is showing "NO" on the left, when I print it with "po success" on the right it is "YES" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple means:

> Right click on the variable in the Variables View and select "Edit
>   Summary Format…". Do you see the string "NO" in there? If so, delete
>   that.
>
> Double clicking on a variable in Xcode 4.x edit's it's summary format,
>   which can be a bit confusing, since you might expect that to edit it's
>   value. We've changed this behavior in Xcode 5 to do nothing.

Comment: I just experienced this same issue with Xcode 5.0.2, only something had set the summary format to "YES".